# Java - Should I read a value in setter?

Tags: java

I have a setter which I want it to check if an email address contains the characters "@" and "." , before setting the value. If the email address does not contain these characters I want the user to enter the email address again. Should I read the new value inside the setter or is it bad pracice and should only be done in main or in a different method?

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Person {
    private String emailAddress;
    Scanner input = new Scanner( System.in);

    public void setEmail(String email)
    {
         while(email.indexOf('@')<0 || email.indexOf('.')<0)
         {
                System.out.println("The email address must contain the characters \"@\" and \".\" ");
                System.out.println("Enter email address again:
                email = input.nextLine();
         }
    }
}
```

Comment: I would validate it, similar to what you're doing, but I would throw an exception if the argument isn't valid.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, this is bad practice.

The problem is that you will get stuck if you call the method in a context where you don't have an interactive console, e.g. in a unit test.

Throw an `IllegalArgumentException`, and let the caller implement the retry (or not).

In your setter:

```
void setEmail(String email) {
  if (!email.contains("@") || !email.contains(".")) {
    throw new IllegalArgumentException("Invalid email: " + email);
  }
  this.emailAddress = email;
}
```

In your caller:

```
while (true) {
  try {
    setEmail(emailAddress);
    break;
  } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
    // Show a message, or whatever.
  }
```

Answer (score 3):

You are mixing functionality and responsibilities here in a bad way.

Yes, the setter should absolutely validate input, this is one of the most common reasons to utilize an accessor method instead of exposing the variable itself.

No, the setter should not make use of `System.in` or `System.out` to request new input from the user. Leave that up to `main` or what have you. This is outside of the scope of the setter's (and `Person` class' responsibilities)

The best methodology here is to use the `IllegalArgumentException` and let the calling code handle that as it wishes.

```
public void setEmail(String email)
{
     if(email.indexOf('@')<0 || email.indexOf('.')<0)
     {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Invalid email address.");
     }
     this.email = email;
}
```

Your client code could then utilize it like so

```
boolean goodEmail = false;
while (!goodEmail) {
  String inputEmail = getTheEmailAddressFromTheUserSomehow();

  try {
    person.setEmail(inputEmail);
    goodEmail = true;
  } catch (IllegalArugmentException e) {
    //try again!
    //or don't, depends on the workflow of the application
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

**In general it's a bad idea if a method does anything other than its name suggests.**

If the method is called `setFoo()`, people expect it to update the field called `foo` and do nothing else. Of course you can (indeed you **should**) validate your input and throw an `IllegalArgumentException` if it isn't what you want, but nothing else.

This is often called "**the principle of least surprise**" and it's a very useful design principle for writing code.

**Another general rule of thumb is that as much as possible, methods should be only responsible for one thing.**

Of course what's a "thing" will vary, it could be something very specific (for example: "this method multiplies the two parameters") or it could be more general ("this method handles all my input"), but if you can't explain in a simple sentence what the method does, it probably does too much.

*(As an exercise, think about how you'd explain to a friend what `setEmail()` does. Say the words out loud. It really works.)*

This is even more important when you're doing I/O, like you do in your example: it should be very-very clear who reads from the `Scanner` and when, otherwise it becomes practically impossible to follow what input is expected at what stage of the program. In this case even your `Person` class shouldn't do anything with the `Scanner`. Handle the input somewhere else and leave the `Person` class to just represent a person.